# Data not loading in Detail View

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, plist, detailsview

I'm trying to get my data to load in my detail view. Can any one take a look and see why it isnt showing? It loads fine in my rootviewcontroller, just not the detail view.

DetailViewController.m

```
 #import "DetailViewController.h"


@implementation DetailViewController




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}



- (void)setIcon:(UIImage *)newIcon
{
    [super setIcon:newIcon];
    iconView.image = newIcon;
}

- (void)setPublisher:(NSString *)newPublisher
{
    [super setPublisher:newPublisher];
    publisherLabel.text = newPublisher;
}


- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName
{
    [super setName:newName];
    nameLabel.text = newName;
}



- (void)dealloc
{
    [iconView release];
    [publisherLabel release];
    [nameLabel release];
    [priceLabel release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

detailviewcontroller.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>




@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *iconView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *publisherLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *priceLabel;

}




@end
```

RootViewControllerPoints.m

```
#import "RootViewControllerPoints.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"




#define USE_INDIVIDUAL_SUBVIEWS_CELL    1

#define DARK_BACKGROUND  [UIColor colorWithRed:151.0/255.0 green:152.0/255.0 blue:155.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define LIGHT_BACKGROUND [UIColor colorWithRed:172.0/255.0 green:173.0/255.0 blue:175.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize tmpCell, data;


#pragma mark View controller methods

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the table view.
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 73.0;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = DARK_BACKGROUND;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    // Load the data.
    NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.data = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            return YES;
        default:
            return NO;
    }
}



#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [data count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ApplicationCell";

    ApplicationCell *cell = (ApplicationCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

#if USE_INDIVIDUAL_SUBVIEWS_CELL
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IndividualSubviewsBasedApplicationCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tmpCell;
        self.tmpCell = nil;

#endif
    }

    // Display dark and light background in alternate rows -- see tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:.
    cell.useDarkBackground = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0);

    // Configure the data for the cell.

    NSDictionary *dataItem = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:[dataItem objectForKey:@"Icon"]];
    cell.publisher = [dataItem objectForKey:@"Publisher"];
    cell.name = [dataItem objectForKey:@"Name"];


    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController. = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}



@end
```

This has been bugging me for quite a while, I've looked at numerous examples, tutorials and even asked other iphone devs. Everything source seems to say something different.

Comment: Add iPhone as a tag. You will get more answers then.

Comment: What is the line "detailViewController. = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" in didSelectRowAtIndexPath supposed to do?  Is that the actual code or a typo in your question?  Why is there a dot after detailViewController?

Comment: ah, it was a line of code another user suggested. While it is typed like that the debugger picks it up as an error. 

If i delete it everything loads fine, though the data is not passed to the subview either.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Yes pleas, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that the setXXX methods in DetailViewController try to make calls to super setXXX but since DetailViewController is a subclass of UIViewController those calls to super will fail because UIViewController doesn't have such methods.  Remove the calls to super in the setXXX methods.

Second problem is that the setXXX methods are setting the controls on the DetailViewController directly but the controls won't be accessible until the view is loaded so it won't work if the methods are called before the pushViewController call.

If you change the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath as follows it should work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
   [detailViewController setName:@"name here"];
   [detailViewController setPublisher:@"publisher here"];
   [detailViewController setIcon:yourImageVariableHere];       
   [detailViewController release];
}
```

Although the above change should work, you might want to consider creating ivars to hold the values in DetailViewController (instead of using the ui controls themselves to hold the data).  Then create properties for them using @property and @synthesize.  The properties can be set immediately after DetailViewController is created and in the viewDidLoad of the view, you can set the ui controls to the property values.  This will give the DetailViewController more control over how its ui is updated, allow you to change the ui without affecting callers, and it doesn't need to be displayed to set its properties.